# Downcasting a generic type in C# 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, generics, downcast

Why can I only upcast a generic and not downcast it?
How is it not clear to the compiler that if my constraint says `where T : BaseClass` and U is derived from BaseClass that `(U)objectOfTypeT` is valid?

Comment: If it helps, note you can add a cast to object in the middle if you want to overrule the compiler.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: That helps a lot. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it might not be valid. Consider this:

```
class Base { }
class A : Base { }
class B : Base { }

A temp1 = new A();
B temp2 = (B)temp1; // not valid
```

Just because they share the same base class does not mean that you can typecast one to the other.

Note that you can get around this by using the `as` operator:

```
var result = objectOfTypeT as U; // this does not give any compilation error
                                 // but will result in a null reference if
                                 // objectOfTypeT cannot be converted to U
```

Comment: Then why not throw an exception just like always? "Cast not valid"

Comment: @the_drow: I can only speculate, but it feels like that would counteract the purpose of generics; one key element of generics is to achieve type safety. Allowing this potentially failing cast would defeat that purpose.

Comment: After searching google a bit. What about covariance and contravariance? Is this what I am looking for?

Comment: @the_drow: it might be. Depends on the context.

Comment: I have a generic unit test for every class that inherits from Base. The only difference is the outcoming result. I can already tell what T will be and only need to downcast it to check the outcoming result.

Comment: @the_drow: it seems you can get around this by using the `as` operator; check updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I read the question wrong, you could have:

```
class A:BaseClass{}
class B:BaseClass{}
```

With T=A and U=B, both constraints are happy, but the cast from T to U is clearly invalid.

If U is just another class, then the same still applies; the T is not known to be in the same chain as U unless you state it in the constraints (generic constraints can involve other generic type arguments, if it helps).

Comment: Well no, I am not casting from T to U but from T to A where T is A and the constraint is where T : BaseClass.

Comment: @the_drow (U)objectOfTypeT is most definitely a cast from T to U